# Scala play http filters: how to find the request body

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

I'm trying to write a filter similar to the simple one described in http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaHttpFilters but I need to access the request body. The documentation below states that "when we invoke next, we get back an Iteratee. You could wrap this in an Enumeratee to do some transformations if you wished." I'm trying to figure out how to wrap the Iteratee so I can get the request body as a string within the filter so I can log that as well.

Comment: Im not sure if i understand the problem but if you have the request then getting the body is simply request.body...

Comment: I only have the request header as Julien stated below

Comment: did you get this to work? I'm also curious how to do this.

Comment: @Setheron I ended up using action composition .. The way filters is written seems to fit more the situation where you only want to read the header as the body is not yet parsed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I spent some time on this.
I am no means a Scala expert but this works pretty well! :)

```
object AccessLog extends EssentialFilter {
  def apply(nextFilter: EssentialAction) = new EssentialAction {
    def apply(requestHeader: RequestHeader) = {
      val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis

      nextFilter(requestHeader).map { result =>
        val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis
        val requestTime = endTime - startTime

        val bytesToString: Enumeratee[ Array[Byte], String ] = Enumeratee.map[Array[Byte]]{ bytes => new String(bytes) } 
        val consume: Iteratee[String,String] = Iteratee.consume[String]()    
        val resultBody : Future[String] = result.body |>>> bytesToString &>> consume

        resultBody.map {
          body =>
            Logger.info(s"${requestHeader.method} ${requestHeader.uri}" +
          s" took ${requestTime}ms and returned ${result.header.status}")
            val jsonBody = Json.parse(body)
            Logger.debug(s"Response\nHeader:\n${result.header.headers.toString}\nBody:\n${Json.prettyPrint(jsonBody)}")
        }

         result.withHeaders("Request-Time" -> requestTime.toString)

      }
    }
  }
```

The end result will print the body as a Json String (pretty printed).

Comment: In Play 2.1.x, value body is not a member of play.api.mvc.Result

Comment: I'm on Play 2.2x http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.SimpleResult

Comment: I'm sorry but this prints the response's body to the request, and not the request's body

Answer (score 7):

First thing you have to know is when the Filter is invoked, the request body is not parsed yet. That's why it's giving you a `RequestHeader`. You'll have to find out the type of body, and call the proper body parser accordingly.

You can find a example of body parsing in the CSRF filter (It can lookup for CSRF tokens in the first bytes of the request body).

See: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-filters-helpers/src/main/scala/csrf.scala#L221-L233.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That seem pretty helpful. I only need to convert the body to a string for logging purposes. My application mainly deals with GET requests or POSTs with JSON body.

Comment: Link to source file is broken

Comment: master changed to main, so this is the file (but don't know which line numbers, since I think they have changed): https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/main/web/play-filters-helpers/src/main/scala/play/filters/csrf/csrf.scala

Answer (score -4):

In the controller method that routes to the action, simply call

```
Map<String, String[]> params = request().queryString();
```

This will get you a map of parameters, where you can then call

```
params.get("someParam")[0]
```

to get the param (if it is a single value). If the param is a list, ignore the indexing andthat will return an array.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I'm trying to access the parameters in a filter global to all requests (all controllers and actions ..etc) so this will not work.