# Access Request Body in essential filter Play Framework 2

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3

I am new to Scala.
As mentioned in play framework official documentation in https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaHttpFilters :

> Play provides a lower level filter API called EssentialFilter which
>   gives you full access to the body of the request.

but there is not any method to accessing request body in `requestHeader` object.

```
import play.api.Logger
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext

object LoggingFilter extends EssentialFilter {
  def apply(nextFilter: EssentialAction) = new EssentialAction {
    def apply(requestHeader: RequestHeader) = {
      val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis
      nextFilter(requestHeader).map { result =>
        val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis
        val requestTime = endTime - startTime
        Logger.info(s"${requestHeader.method} ${requestHeader.uri}" +
          s" took ${requestTime}ms and returned ${result.header.status}")
        result.withHeaders("Request-Time" -> requestTime.toString)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You have access to the query string, the parameters and headers. Which kind of info would you like to get from there?

Comment: The body of request , all HTTP methods support body ( expect GET). and I need to intercept request bodies

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17822416/scala-play-http-filters-how-to-find-the-request-body).

Comment: I see that! that is for response body, Responses are different from requests!

Answer (score 5):

The abstract method `EssentialFilter.apply` that you implement when you create an `EssentialFilter` returns an `EssentialAction` which basically is a function that goes from `RequestHeader` to an `Iteratee[Array[Byte], Result]` into which play will feed the incoming byte chunks of the http body.

If you aren't familiar with the iteratee API, the signature above basically means, a thing that will accept chunks of data of the type `Array[Byte]` and sooner or later produce a `Result` out of those.

The normal play `Action`'s is a subclass of `EssentialAction` that parses the body using a `BodyParser` and then feeding the result of that (`Request` which is both request headers and the parsed body) into a function that in turn returns a `Future[Result]`

So if you only have one filter, then `next: EssentialAction` in your filter is basically the actual controller action. That you get to take its `Iteratee[Array[Bytes], Result]` and wrap it with something is what makes it possible to access the body of the request, before the body parser has gotten to touch it.

So to achieve what you want will require you to learn a bit about how `Iteratees` works and how to use  `Enumeratees` to transform or peek into data fed into an iteratee.

#### Some starting points

The play framework docs has got some pretty good information about iteratees: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Iteratees

There is also a nice blog article by James Roper (play tech lead) that might help:
https://jazzy.id.au/2012/11/06/iteratees_for_imperative_programmers.html

#### Important note

How filters works in play makes it impossible to look at the parsed body with a filter. Unless you make an enumeratee that will parse the body but still pass the bytes on to the actual action (this will have you parsing the body twice).

If this is what you want you may be better off working with the `ActionBuilder` and creating your own custom `Action` that will allow you to look at the parsed request.

Comment: I'm working on an `EssentialFilter` which should introspect URL-encoded forms and perform actions based on specific values in this form.
I want to do this for all requests, as I want to implement the equivalent of: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#how-do-forms-with-patch-put-or-delete-methods-work-questionmark
I was thinking of using: `BodyParsers.parse.urlFormEncoded.apply(request)` for this, however it is unclear what is the  best way to consume the iteratee, introspect the form and then forward it.
Would you have an example of how to do this Johan?

Comment: Sorry, nothing from the top of my head. Ask on the playframework gitter channel or mailing list!

Comment: all is nice but would be much nicer to show an example in the answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

you don't want to parse request body on filtering level because of  the body not parsed on filtering process, you have to buffer, parse and stream so it is better to use action composition

```
    object LoggingAction extends ActionBuilder[Request] {
      def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[Result]) = {
          Logger.debug(request.body.asInstanceOf[AnyContentAsJson].json.toString())    
          block(request)
  }
}
```

on controller side use like

```
 def index = LoggingAction {...
```