# How to get request body content on EssentialFilter

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.5

We are trying to get a body content on EssentialFilter with Play 2.5.x but it's not visible.

Do you know a right way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access Request Body in essential filter Play Framework 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29047510/access-request-body-in-essential-filter-play-framework-2)