# Intercepting request body xml in scala Filter

Tags: scala, playframework

I am new to scala and working to figure out how I can intercept request body in filter, validate it's content, and if found valid then proceed to next filter/controller. I saw accepted answer in

[Scala play http filters: how to find the request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17822416/scala-play-http-filters-how-to-find-the-request-body)

but it looks like it is reading response body and operating on it. Also, I read through :

https://jazzy.id.au/2013/02/16/understanding_the_play_filter_api.html

and I am not clear how I can implement what is said in there as :

```
If you want to parse the body at the filter level, then you'll have to buffer it, parse it, and then stream it again for the action to parse again.
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but action composition might be a simpler tool: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaActionsComposition

Comment: At the time where the filter is applied you don't have a body so @rethab is right. You should use action composition.

Comment: But I want to intercept request and read it's request body to validate before the request reaches to controller, so is it possible to intercept request between filter(s) and controller using action composition? Is there any example to do achieve it, can you please share the link?